# DAY CQ5.4 xtype Dropdown

Tags: aem, day-cq

**Day cq5**
how do i change the width of a dropdown in cq. Cuerrently it has a fixed width of around 279px, To get a dropdown i specified the type as select and xtype as selection.

Answer (score 1):

The [selection widget](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection) has a width property that you should be able to set to the width you want.  If you haven't already tried that I'd obviously start there...